# add a background to a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add a background to a div.

Using this CSS works as expected:

```
background: url('../images/badge2.png') ;
```

. . .  but when I use this CSS instead of the above, it doesn't work.

```
$('#offerDiv').css("background", "url('../images/badge2.png')");
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

Comment: Please give me error messages and the state of the element after you executed this code.

Comment: add your html code

Comment: Most likely, it is as the answer on this page suggests, a path-problem.

Comment: add some content your div other wise not showing background or  add some height & width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to avoid applying pure CSS rules and only deal with classes in JavaScript code. You can create a CSS class, e.g.:

```
.styledDiv {
  background: url('../images/badge2.png');
}
```

And then use jQuery [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) function to apply this CSS class to an element:

```
$('#offerDiv').addClass("styledDiv");
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 5):

It is because, `url()` in CSS should be relative to where it is being used. Let's consider this case.

```
- index.html
- css/
  - style.css
- img
  - badge.png
```

In the `style.css` you need to set:

```
background: url("../img/badge.png");
```

While, if you are setting it on the element using JavaScript, you are setting it on the HTML file, where the URL changes, with respect to the HTML file, where the CSS is parsed. So from the HTML file, it's sibling's (`img`) child (`badge.png`):

```
background: url("img/badge.png");
```

But in the CSS file, it is its parent's (`../`) sibling's (`img`) child (`badge.png`). Is this clear enough?